# What distribution is $P_X(x \mid K, N) = \frac{1}{ ( 1 + N)^K} {x + K -1 \choose x} \left( \frac{N}{1+N}\right)^x$?

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, distribution-identification, discrete-distributions

What kind of distribution is the following:

$$
 P_X(x \mid K, N) = \frac{1}{ ( 1 + N)^K} {x + K -1 \choose x} \left( \frac{N}{1+N}\right)^x
$$

and how can I find $P_X(x < x_0 \mid K, N)$?

Comment: See the negative binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the answer is negative binomial as @TMat suggested. I needed to rearrange the terms.